# doubt on struts and filter

Tags: java, struts

Assume it is a struts project..

the filter configuration is as follows,

```
<filter>
<filter-name>samplefilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.samplepack.SampleFilterXXX</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>samplefilter</filter-name>
<servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

and the servlet mapping is as follows,

```
<servlet-mapping>
<servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
<url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

I want to know whether the samplefilter will be executed for every action class in the struts project?
can you post the situations whereever i can apply this effectively ?

Comment: when giving negative rating post the reason too,so that others can improve..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is Yes, provided that all your struts actions are accessed via the pattern `*.do`. This is the default configuration for Struts, so I expect that this is the case.

However as the Struts mapping us configurable, it is possible for you to define a different mapping to access a Struts action, and therefore your filter will not be picked up. But, as mentioned above, this is uncommon practice, so I expect you will be okay.